# Microsoft Access 2010 SQL Split String at "X" and Multiply

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table with a package size column with a data type of text that I need to convert to an integer for mathmatical reasons. The values in this column typically look something like "100ML","20GM","UD 20","13OZ" here is where it gets tricky there are occasionally values like "6X12ML","UD 5X6ML". The ones with the "X" in them I need to remove the "ML" I'm currently doing this with

```
Replace([TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN_NAME],"ML","")
```

in an expression column in a query. I can use nested Replace functions to remove the "ML","GM","OZ" and "UD ". All of my attempts to do this have failed, I figured the end solution would be something like

```
IIf([TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN_NAME] Like "X", (CInt(Left([TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN_NAME],InStr(1,[TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN_NAME],"X")-1))*CInt(Right([TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN_NAME],InStr(1,[TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN_NAME],"X")+1))),[TABLE_NAME].[COLUMN_NAME])
```

I have tried using a variation of the code above with no avail. All suggestions are appreciated, I would preffer to get this knocked out in one query but I do realize I can use and expression and just split the text before and after the "X" into two differenct expression columns. Then use another query to multiply the values.

Comment: Correct if the input is "UD 5X6ML" I would like to output in a column containing 30.

Comment: I knew how to describe it in psuedo terms, but I couldn't turn psuedo into source. I was finally able to create a well functioning source. If anyone is interested look below at the source I wrote to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
QTY_ORDERED: IIf(InStr(1,Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([STANDARD_PRICING].[PACKAGE_AMOUNT],"GM",""),"ML",""),"UD","")," ",""),"X")>1,[CRX_HISTORIC_PO].[QUANTITY]/Left(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([STANDARD_PRICING].[PACKAGE_AMOUNT],"GM",""),"ML",""),"UD","")," ",""),InStr(1,Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([STANDARD_PRICING].[PACKAGE_AMOUNT],"GM",""),"ML",""),"UD","")," ",""),"X")-1)*Right(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([STANDARD_PRICING].[PACKAGE_AMOUNT],"GM",""),"ML",""),"UD","")," ",""),Len(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([STANDARD_PRICING].[PACKAGE_AMOUNT],"GM",""),"ML",""),"UD","")," ",""))-InStr(1,Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([STANDARD_PRICING].[PACKAGE_AMOUNT],"GM",""),"ML",""),"UD","")," ",""),"X"))*-1,[CRX_HISTORIC_PO].[QUANTITY]/Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace([STANDARD_PRICING].[PACKAGE_AMOUNT],"GM",""),"ML",""),"UD","")," ","")*-1)
```

The code above is what I used to complete the task at hand.